# Reading Simple json data in android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to read simple JSON data in android without using a URL.

Here is my following JSON data. Can any one help me in reading of following data?

```
{"_id":"550ac135a2c513115c6cfa32","UserID":195,"LoginName":"Asdfa","EmailAddress":"adifa1@gmail.com","Password":"Head","Gender":1,"DateOfBirthString":"5-21-1988","DateOfBirth":"1988-05-21T00:00:00","DOB":"21/05/1988","CreatedDate":"2015-03-19T12:29:40.313Z","Status":"P","UserAge":26,"PreffredMaxAge":99,"PreffredMinAge":21,"ProfilePhoto":null,"IsUserOnline":false,"IsUserHomo":false,"ZipCode":"","IsUserSubscribed":false,"ProfileCompletionPoints":-1.0,"LastOnlineTime":null}
```

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: ues json, that would help you

Comment: I have taken entire data into a string trying to read it, based upon (Key,Value) pairs

Comment: can anyone provide me any live example

Comment: what are you trying to make with those tag

Comment: @PankajNimgade I am doing login action in my application after providing corresponding credentials, it returning above tag's. I want to display above tags in textview

Answer (score 1):

Please create a model class for User with setter gatter for all property (ids name, photo etc.).
I am creating only for id.

```
public class AppUser{
private string id,

public void getId(){
return id;
}

public void setId(String id){
this.id = id;
}
```

and create a array list for AppUser type.

```
ArrayList<AppUser> userlist = new ArrayList<AppUser>();
```

Now parse data :

```
String serverData = "your server response in json";

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(serverdata);

                        String id= jsonObj .getString("_id");
                        String userID = phone.getString("UserID");
                        ................//parse other attribute 
AppUser user = new AppUser();
user.setId(id);
................// for other attribute 

//save into arraylist

userlist.add(user);
```

For more detail please follow below tutorials:

http://mrbool.com/how-to-use-json-to-parse-data-into-android-application/28944

http://androidexample.com/JSON_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=71&aaid=95

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this..as simple

URL myURL = new URL("your url");

URLConnection tc = myURL.openConnection();

BufferedReader in //read line using InputStreamReader with obj "tc"

```
 String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);

    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
    listItems.add(jo.getString("text")); // add in list view
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new JSONObject and pass in the json string as a argument.

```
    try {
        json_object = new JSONObject(json_str);
    } catch (JSONException) {
        //thrown when it cannot parse the json
      ;
    }
```